# Hereditarily countable set and $L_{\omega_1}(x)$

Tags: set-theory

> If $x \in H_{\aleph_1}$, then $L_{\omega_1}(x) \subset H_{\aleph_1}$.

Here, what exactly is $L_{\omega_1} (x)$? And can anyone show an example of how to form hereditarily countable set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make sense of $L_{\omega_1}(x)$, you should first have a basic understanding of $L$, the [constructible universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe); the description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe#What_is_L.3F) is as understandable a short description as you’re likely to find. The same idea is used to define $L_\alpha(x)$ for a set $x$, the universe of sets constructible from $x$; it’s described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe#Relative_constructibility).

A set $x$ is hereditarily countable if it is countable, and each of its elements is hereditarily countable. Alternatively, $x$ is hereditarily countable if it is countable, and so is each element of its [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set). The countable ordinals are handy examples of hereditarily countable sets.

The idea behind the theorem that you quote is that if you start with a hereditarily countable set, you can define only countably many things from it in one step, so each $L_\alpha(x)$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$ will still be countable, and indeed hereditarily so.

Answer (score 1):

The constructible universe is denoted by $L$, and it is constructed by a transfinite induction, where the $\alpha$-th stage is denoted by $L_\alpha$.

We can talk about relative constructibility, which is the same construction only we start with a transitive set which may not be the empty set as in $L$. We use $L(x)$ to denote the sets constructed in this fashion when we began with the transitive closure of $x$.

To say that $x\in H_{\omega_1}$ is to say that $x$ has a countable transitive closure. And $L_{\omega_1}(x)$ is the set of all those which were constructed at countable levels from the transitive closure of $x$.

To show this, prove by induction that if $x\in H_{\omega_1}$ then $L_\alpha(x)$ is countable for every countable ordinal. Since $L_\alpha(x)$ is always a transitive set, and it is countable, it must be a subset of $H_{\omega_1}$, and so must be $L_{\omega_1}(x)$.